# PHP: mcrypt_ecb is not working inside a function

Tags: php, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I've got a very simple function:

```
$me = 45S237s53dsSerwjw53s23rjf; //Some long encrypted string.

function decrypt($user){
    $user = pack("H*" , $user); //Converting from hexadecimal to binary

    $user = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $user, MCRYPT_DECRYPT); //Decrypting

    return $user;
}
```

The problem is if I do go `echo decrypt($me);` it doesn't work, I don't end up with a decrypted string.

However if I do essentially the same thing without using a `function` it works:

```
    $user = $me;        

    $user = pack("H*" , $user);

    $user = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $user, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);

    echo $user; //Works fine...
```

What's going on here?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-ecb.php): This function is deprecated and should not be used anymore, see mcrypt_generic() and mdecrypt_generic() for replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the `$key` variable inside the function body. With the correct error level settings you'd have been given a warning, that `$key` is undefined.

Either add `$key` as a function argument or define `$key` inside the function body (or, third alternative, import `$key` from the global scope).

#### 1

```
function decrypt($user, $key){
    //...
}
```

#### 2

```
function decrypt($user){
    $key = '....whatever...';
    //...
}
```

#### 3.1

```
function decrypt($user){
    global $key;
    //...
}
```

#### 3.2

```
function decrypt($user){
    //...
    $user = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $GLOBALS['key'], $user, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
    //...
}
```

Comment: goddammit that's it! thank you, accepting as answer in ~8 min